# Verb position when using doch in subordinate clauses

Tags: verb, sentence-structure, word-order, subordinate-clause, rules

I have recently come across several sentences using "doch" in subordinate clauses with different orderings (the examples come from Linguee, usually from europarl.europa.eu) :

(1) some are build as ",doch + Subject + Verb + ..."

> Ich verstehe Ihre Bedenken, doch ich möchte mich aus dieser Diskussion
> besser heraushalten.

> Der Panzerbezug soll nicht für jeden Besucher ersichtlich sein, doch
> ich mag Gebäude, die ihr Umfeld nachhallen lassen

(2) others are build as ",doch + Verb + Subject + ..."

> Er wird das sicher nicht tun, doch wollte ich das auf jeden Fall im
> Namen der Rentner hervorheben.

> Mir persönlich wäre es lieber, es würde keinen Stichtag geben, doch
> denke ich, dass der Vorschlag der Kommission die praktikable
> Höchstgrenze darstellt.

Is there a rule I could use to know when to apply (1) and when to apply (2) ?

Is it connected to the existence of a second subordinate clause (", doch denke ich, dass du recht bist") ?

EDIT : here is my original sentence : "Ich bin ganz fertig mit meiner Arbeit, doch wollte ich dir für die wunderbaren Rückmeldungen danken, die du mir immer schreibst"

Answer (score 4):

Both constructions are always possible, and this has nothing to do with the second subclause. But the second alternative will always sound more formal (on top of the already formal choice of "doch" rather than "aber").